# Creating table in different user's schema(B) in oracle 12c. This user B should have only Select Privileges

Tags: oracle

I wanted to created a restricted user for my application from security point of view. I want to use this restricted user to access my application.

The problem is that - when i create a user in Oracle and insert tables from SYSDba account into its Schema. I am able to drop the table when accessed from newly created schema, although i did not provide drop privilege to this user.

Answer (score 0):

a user ALWAYS has full privs on the objects in THEIR schema - they are the OWNER. you have to put the tables in another account, and then grant SELECT on them to schema.B